# FOREACH syntax in NEO4J

Tags: foreach, neo4j

Error using the FOREACH syntax.

```
CASE WHEN i.IOType STARTS WITH 'D' THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS isDigital,
    CASE WHEN i.IOType STARTS WITH 'A' THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS isAnalog 
       FOREACH(_ IN isAnalog | 
        MERGE(aa:AnalogAlarm {tag: signalTag })
        WHERE i.signalTag CONTAINS aa.tag
        MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(aa))
        FOREACH(_ IN isDigital | 
        MERGE(dig:DigitalAlarm {tag: signalTag })
        WHERE i.signalTag CONTAINS dig.tag
        MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(dig))
```

So I am unable to use the WHERE clause in FOREACH. What would be the appropriate syntax?

Comment: What is the error message? Which Neo4j version?

Comment: Invalid input 'WHERE': expected
  "("
  ")"
  "CALL"
  "CREATE"
  "DELETE"
  "DETACH"
  "FOREACH"
  "LOAD"
  "MATCH"
  "MERGE"
  "NODETACH"
  "ON"
  "OPTIONAL"
  "REMOVE"
  "RETURN"
  "SET"
  "UNWIND"
  "USE"
  "WITH" (line 33, column 9 (offset: 1623))
"        WHERE i.signalTag CONTAINS aa.tag"
         ^

Comment: This is the error message

Comment: Is `signalTag` actually `i.signalTag`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `signalTag` comes from, so I will just replicate it being available with a `WITH` clause at the start of the query.

I am guessing that what you want is for every existing node whose property `signalTag` equals the `signalTag` value, you want to create a new node with property `tag` = `signalTag`. If the `IOType` of the existing node starts with `'A'`, then the new node gets the label `AnalogAlarm`, or if it starts with `'D'`, then it gets the `DigitalAlarm` label instead. The new node is then connected to the existing node(s) with an `IS_ALARM` relationship.

If that is true, you can achieve it with a couple of `CALL` subqueries:

```sql
WITH 'ABC' AS signalTag
CALL {
    WITH signalTag
    MATCH (i WHERE i.signalTag = signalTag AND i.IOType STARTS WITH 'A')
    MERGE (aa:AnalogAlarm {tag: signalTag})
    MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(aa)
}
CALL {
    WITH signalTag
    MATCH (j WHERE j.signalTag = signalTag AND j.IOType STARTS WITH 'D')
    MERGE (dig:DigitalAlarm {tag: signalTag})
    MERGE (j)-[:IS_ALARM]->(dig)
}
```

The `CALL` subqueries are necessary so that the cardinality of the contained `MATCH` clauses don't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has many syntax errors and the use case is a bit too complex for the `FOREACH` clause, especially since there are better alternatives that were introduced to simplify such use cases.

*Note: my answers assume that `signalTag` should actually be `i.signalTag`, in which case your `WHERE` tests are not needed.*

#### Snippet using [CALL subquery POST-UNION processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/call-subquery/#call-post-union):

```
...

CALL {
  WITH i
  WITH i WHERE i.IOType STARTS WITH 'A'
  MERGE (a:AnalogAlarm {tag: i.signalTag})
  MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(a)
  RETURN a

  UNION ALL

  WITH i
  WITH i WHERE i.IOType STARTS WITH 'D'
  MERGE (a:DigitalAlarm {tag: i.signalTag})
  MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(a)
  RETURN a

  UNION ALL

  WITH i
  WITH i WHERE NOT LEFT(i.IOType, 1) IN ['A', 'D']
  RETURN NULL AS a
}

// Remainder of query
...
```

The remainder of the query can access `a`, which will be `NULL` if `i.IOType` does not start with 'A' or 'D'.

#### Snippet using [apoc.do.case](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc/apoc.do.case/)

```
...

CALL apoc.do.case([
  i.IOType STARTS WITH 'A',
    'MERGE(a:AnalogAlarm {tag: i.signalTag}) MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(a) RETURN a',
  i.IOType STARTS WITH 'D',
    'MERGE(a:DigitalAlarm {tag: i.signalTag}) MERGE (i)-[:IS_ALARM]->(a) RETURN a'
  ],
  'RETURN NULL AS a',
  {i: i}
) YIELD value

// Remainder of query
...
```

The remainder of the query can access `a` (via `value.a`), which will be `NULL` if `i.IOType` does not start with 'A' or 'D'.